# Docker HEALTHCHECK CMD won't return success even with "exit 0"

Tags: docker

The question is in the title. I am attempting to setup health checks but the `HEALTCHECK` is always failing no matter what i put in for the args array.

`[ "exit 0"]`, `[ "CMD", "exit 0" ]`, `[ "CMD-SHELL", "exit 0" ]`, nothing works.

The container is always marked as `unhealthy`.

Here is my full command from the `Dockerfile`.

```
HEALTHCHECK --interval=30s --timeout=10s --start-period=1m --retries=3 CMD [ "CMD-SHELL", "/healthcheck.sh" ]
```

I've confirmed running a the folowing on the container returns `0`.

```
> /healthcheck.sh && echo $?
> 0
```

This has the same result, not that it matters.

```
> /bin/sh /healthcheck.sh && echo $?
> 0
```

My `/healcheck.sh` script is dead simple.

```
#!/bin/sh

tile38-cli HEALTHZ | grep -q true

RESULT=$?

echo "health check exited with status $RESULT"

exit $RESULT
```

What gives?

Comment: `exit 0` is a shell command. When you pass an array, you disable implicit shell use altogether.

Comment: See `man execve` to see how command execution works under the hood. At the OS level, it _doesn't_ involve a shell until someone puts that shell in the argument vector to _make_ one be involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, when i specify the command with `[]` that specifies that it uses the default `SHELL` which on Linux is `/bin/sh -c`. This means its trying to execute my script as a raw command, not a script.

The solution is to remove the `[]`.

```
HEALTHCHECK CMD /app/healthcheck.sh || exit 1
```

Comment: No. Passing a JSON array tells the command to use NO IMPLICIT SHELL AT ALL, it doesn't tell it to use the default shell.

Comment: `HEALTHCHECK CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "exit 0"]` would work just fine, for example; that's _explicitly_ using the default `/bin/sh` shell.